# C# Unit testing class with a private constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Ok so i just got an assignment where i have to perform unit testing on a class with a private constructor.

Now how am i suppose to do unit testing without initializing a class when all the methods are also non static.

Is there any way i can do unit testing(without reflection)on a class with a private constructor ?

Comment: basically, not possible without reflection, but you can post your code sample to see whether it can be worked around

Comment: How do you create instances of these classes? Factory Method? Singleton? I love when unit tests show design issues in your code.

Comment: I guess, the class is a Singleton. Can you confirm?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the class to your question to provide more context?

Comment: nop its not a singleton class. it just has 2 overloaded private constructors and 2 private methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this class has a private constructor, is this to be used publicly? If not, it may be best not to unit test it. If this is the case, the code that is public should test this code in itself by calling it.

Unit testing is there to test what is to be used by the public - by interfacing code in between application layers for instance. Take an input, I want this output. That is really what unit testing is about. Unit testing doesn't care what is in the actual method. As long as it returns what you want, performs the desired action, you have a pass.

Comment: well infact there is nothing public in the class at all.

Comment: @WinCoder Then how the hell do you use it?

Comment: well today when i asked for clarification i have been told that i have to infact correct the mistakes in the code too. Like making stuff public....

Comment: A private constructor can be used to protect state, such as the case of DDD entities, while enabling libraries like entity framework to still instantiate the class. While public constructors only exist with parameters that can instantiate the entity in a valid state. Creating an (invalid) entity via the private constructor is plenty for testing the behavior of individual methods. It's an unnecessary amount of setup to try and mock all the other requirements for the entity (Many of which have private or internal constructors of their own)...

Comment: Often a class has static method(s) to create instances instead of calling `new`.

Answer (score 17):

If you cannot make the class public, you can still test it easily by creating an instance of it this way:

```
var anInstance = (YourPrivateClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourPrivateClass), true);
```

This will give you an instance of your class that you can then populate.

Another helpful testing bit is if you have internal methods (not private), you can access them by making internals visible to your test class. You add this line in assemblyinfo.cs of the class with the internal methods:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourSolution.Tests")]
```

Comment: How can you create a fake / mock instance and not a real one?

Comment: this doesn't work if the parameterless constructor is private

Answer (score 2):

You should be testing through a public API -- there must be *some* way that the class you want to test is instantiated and used.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are typically written and run to ensure that code meets its design and behaves as intended.

Creating a `non-static` class on which you cannot create an instance i.e. private constructor(s) only, might never be useful, in otherwords its is never `Unit Testable`.

In order to be Unit testable:

1. You should be able to create an instance of the class.
2. Testable Function should be either **Public or Internal**.
   You could test Internal function by making your assembly as a [Friend Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a singleton and you don't want the public constructor for the class.
Decorate the constructor with:
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]