# Get instance of class with private constructor for test

Tags: c#, .net, prtg

during testing I need an instance of the following class `public class WmiServiceTarget : SensorTarget<WmiServiceTarget>` that has the following constructor:

```
private WmiServiceTarget(string raw): base(raw)
    {
        DisplayName = components[1];
        Description = components[2];
        Status = components[3].XmlToEnum<WmiServiceStatus>();
    }
```

In the `SensorTarget` the constructor:

```
protected SensorTarget(string raw)
    {
        if (raw == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("raw");
        }

        this.raw = raw;
        components = raw.Split(new char[1]
        {
            '|'
        });
        Name = components[0];
    }
```

Is there a way of getting an instance of WmiServiceTarget.

All classes can be found in https://github.com/lordmilko/PrtgAPI

Comment: I'd assume you get an instance the same way you do everywhere else where you need one.

Comment: Diving into your code a little [this](https://github.com/lordmilko/PrtgAPI/blob/f5865c5c46be435edfbc43759f955ce8a5223846/src/PrtgAPI/Objects/Models/SensorTarget/WmiServiceTarget.cs#L46) line is the only place you're creating an instance of `WmiServiceTarget`, you could add the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute to your assembly to expose this method to your unit test project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663983/c-sharp-unit-testing-class-with-a-private-constructor | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957794/unit-testing-class-with-private-constructor-created-from-factory-method/23958212